# No error when the vbs code is run on remote computer

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, vbscript

I hoped this vbs code would execute the oShell.run methods on the remote machine. This doesn't seem to be the case but there is no error shown when this script executes.

```
on error resume next

dim oShell, strComputer, intProcessID

strComputer = InputBox("IP or Host Name:", "DELETER - serdaruzun@outlook.com")

set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell") & strComputer

oShell.run "cmd.exe /C rd \\%PC%\Users\1*.* /s /q", null, null, intProcessID
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C rd \\%PC%\Users\2*.* /s /q", null, null, intProcessID
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C rd \\%PC%\Users\3*.* /s /q", null, null, intProcessID
set oShell = nothing
```

What is the correct way to execute those commands on a remote computer?

Comment: Try removing & strComputer at the 4th line/

Comment: Will vbscript work on remote pc after removing & strComputer

Comment: Of course not, but you can't do it this way.
Either switch to Powershell or use PSExec in your commands.

Comment: But I can do different cmd commands via different vbs?

Comment: You better take a look at [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx) or [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) as suggested earlier...

Comment: I understand and thank you but We have to use VBS ...

Comment: As it currently stands, **this question should *not* be migrated;** it will almost certainly be shot down virtually instantly.

Answer (score 7):

first of all - if you removed "on error resume next", you would have seen this error immediately.

Next, I would recommend you try using the folder delete method on the remote PC instead of running cmd.

After that, you cannot run cmd.exe against C:\ and somehow make it run against a remote PC uless you launch the VBS with psexec or similar and target a remote PC.

I think this is closer to what you are after:

```
'First, we get the host name
strComputerName = InputBox ("Enter Hostname or IP to delete from")

'Next, we check the user actually entered a name or IP - you missed this!
if len(strComputerName) < 1 then
    WScript.Echo "No Computer Name Entered - Quitting"
    WScript.Quit
end if

'next, we check it exists - you missed this bit too!  no point in trying to remove folders from a non existant PC
If Reachable(strComputerName) Then
    DeleteAFolder("\\" & strComputerName & "\c$\users\me\desktop\test")
    DeleteAFolder("\\" & strComputerName & "\C$\folder\folder2")
Else 
    WScript.Echo "Computer is Unreachable! - Quitting!"
End If


'This function is the one called to check if the computer is reachable in line 11!
Function Reachable(strComputerName)
    Dim wmiQuery, objWMIService, objPing, objStatus
    wmiQuery = "Select * From Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & strComputerName & "'"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set objPing = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)
    For Each objStatus in objPing
        If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) Or objStatus.Statuscode<>0 Then
            Reachable = False 'if computer is unreacable, return false
        Else
            Reachable = True 'if computer is reachable, return true
        End If
    Next
End Function

'This function takes the name of the folders (lines 12 and 13) and deletes them
Sub DeleteAFolder(filespec)
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   'True in the line below includes read only folders
   fso.DeleteFolder(filespec, true)
End Sub
```

Just a quick note.. if this doesn't work - its probably a permissions thing, but I have no intention of expanding this script - so you're on your own from here.

Comment: Code will work again; If I change this line [DeleteAFolder("\\" & strComputerName & "\c$\users\me\desktop\test")] with [DeleteAFolder("\\" & strComputerName & "\c$\users\1*.*")] ?

Comment: no.  you will need to either delete \c$\users\1 or lookup adding a function for deleting files.  This only deletes a folder

Comment: how can add a function to your script in order to delete folders starting with 1 or 2 or 3...

Comment: Lookup folder enumeration and store the folder names in an array and then delete from there.  I'm not a rent a coder service.  You are putting in no effort to even try and figure it out yourself.  You are on your own from here

Comment: Thank you :( I think I have been misunderstood. Sorry :(

Comment: If you think you have been misunderstood, try to explain your exact problem and I will help, but you have to show willing and try to figure it out first

Comment: It gave error for this: ==> fso.DeleteFolder(filespec, true) <== It says: Brackets can not be used when calling the sub procedure (routine)

Comment: Unfortunately that it not an error.  Can you please post a new question with the error message and I will be able to look at debugging with you providing you have made some effort on modifying my script.

Comment: I use Turkish NotePad++ . So I hope I coud translate the error correctly :)

Comment: I removed ==> ,true <== and It didnt give the error...

Comment: well done :)  glad you figured it out

Comment: It doesnt give the error but your script doesnt work :( It didnt delete anythink...

Comment: like i said, start a new question.. and the script as i provided it does work and was tested before submission